# SQLite3 Maximum Column Width (text)

Tags: android, sql

I am building a java object that holds an array of strings that represent file paths. I want to store this object in a SQLite database, and I've written the code to do most of it, but I want to know if there is a maximum width for a column [on Android's precompiled one]. If there isn't I might be able to serialize the object or store it so it doesn't have to continue to add columns if another one of these objects is inserted into the list with more files than previous ones, and I can't find any documentation if there is an actual limit. I don't expect paths to be more than 256 characters but there could be those crazy ones who love their file paths...

So my question is: What is the maximum width of a SQLite 3 [android] column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serializing file paths into one field sounds pretty inefficient,but to answer your question, there is a reason you have trouble finding the max, because you can adjust it during compile time: http://sqlite.org/limits.html#max_length

The default limit is 1 billion bytes, so you have quite a lot of space.

Comment: I guess I should have specified a bit more - The one for android. I'm not going to be compiling it.

Comment: @Mgamerz: It doesn't get more specific: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#getMaximumSize()

Comment: Thanks, I guess we'll find out when someone makes a huge json array.